# MySQL - Correlated subqueries fail, column in where clause is unknwon

Tags: mysql

I have a complex mysql query with multple subqueries. I need one of that subqueries are related to main table. Thats my query:

```
SELECT table_cl.id, table_cl.nombre, table_cl.apellidos, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
            SELECT iauno.id_accion, iauno.id_cliente, iauno.asistencia
            FROM inter_clientes_acciones iauno
            INNER JOIN clientes clientesuno ON clientesuno.id = iauno.id_cliente
            WHERE iauno.id_cliente IN(
                SELECT iasubuno.id_cliente
                FROM inter_clientes_acciones iasubuno
                INNER JOIN acciones acsubuno ON iasubuno.id_accion = acsubuno.id
                WHERE acsubuno.id_proyecto = 3
                GROUP BY iasubuno.id_accion 
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
            ) 
        )caa
    ) as convocado,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
            SELECT iados.id_accion, iados.id_cliente, iados.asistencia
            FROM inter_clientes_acciones iados
            INNER JOIN clientes cldos ON cldos.id = iados.id_cliente
            WHERE iados.id_cliente IN(
                SELECT iasubdos.id_cliente
                FROM inter_clientes_acciones iasubdos
                INNER JOIN acciones acsubdos ON iasubdos.id_accion = acsubdos.id
                WHERE acsubdos.id_proyecto = 3 AND iasubdos.id_cliente = table_cl.id
                GROUP BY id_accion 
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
            ) 
        )car
    ) as realizado 
FROM clientes table_cl
WHERE table_cl.id_proyecto = 3 AND table_cl.id IN (
    SELECT iatres.id_cliente
    FROM inter_clientes_acciones iatres
    INNER JOIN clientes cltres ON cltres.id = iatres.id_cliente
    WHERE iatres.id_cliente IN(
        SELECT iasubtres.id_cliente
        FROM inter_clientes_acciones iasubtres
        INNER JOIN acciones acsubtres ON iasubtres.id_accion = acsubtres.id
        WHERE acsubtres.id_proyecto = 3
        GROUP BY iasubtres.id_accion 
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        ) 
)
```

When I execute the query, I get the error `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'table_cl.id' in 'where clause'`

How I modify the query to reference the id on table_cl??

**EDIT:**

Maybe an explain is required: I have 3 tables, clients, actions and clients_actions (said in spanish: clientes, acciones and inter_clientes_acciones). An action can be created for **one client** or for **multiple client**. The purpose of this query is to get this fields: name and surname of the client, number of actions asigned to the client, and number of this actions which the client had assisted, but only the actions (individual actions) assigned to him.

Here you have an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05136/3/0) with the schema and the failing SQL I made.

**-> EDIT 2:**
I have found an alternative way to get the data. In this case I group all the actions ID in a field and (in the PHP file) I count it. I had this response:

```
Individual actions: [ { "nombre": "Susana", "apellidos": "Rodr\u00edguez Torr\u00f3n", "acc_convocadas": "2,3,5", "acc_realizadas": "2" }, { "nombre": "Pablo", "apellidos": "Campos P\u00e9rez", "acc_convocadas": "5", "acc_realizadas": "-" }, { "nombre": "Oscar", "apellidos": "Delacroix", "acc_convocadas": "-", "acc_realizadas": "-" } ]
Group actions: [ { "nombre": "Susana", "apellidos": "Rodr\u00edguez Torr\u00f3n", "acc_convocadas": "3,1,4", "acc_realizadas": "-" }, { "nombre": "Pablo", "apellidos": "Campos P\u00e9rez", "acc_convocadas": "-", "acc_realizadas": "-" }, { "nombre": "Oscar", "apellidos": "Delacroix", "acc_convocadas": "3", "acc_realizadas": "-" } ]
```

This is the clause

```
SELECT nombre, apellidos,
  IFNULL((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id_accion)
     FROM inter_clientes_acciones iac
     WHERE iac.id_cliente = cl.id AND id_accion IN (
       SELECT iauno.id_accion
       FROM inter_clientes_acciones iauno
       INNER JOIN acciones acuno ON iauno.id_accion = acuno.id
       WHERE acuno.id_proyecto = 3
       GROUP BY iauno.id_accion
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     )), "-") as acc_convocadas,
  IFNULL((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id_accion)
      FROM inter_clientes_acciones iac
      WHERE iac.id_cliente = cl.id AND asistencia = 1 AND id_accion IN (
        SELECT iauno.id_accion
        FROM inter_clientes_acciones iauno
        INNER JOIN acciones acuno ON iauno.id_accion = acuno.id
        WHERE acuno.id_proyecto = 3
        GROUP BY iauno.id_accion
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)), "-") as acc_realizadas
FROM clientes cl
WHERE id_proyecto = 3
```

Comment: I'd be surprised (and a little impressed) if anyone around here fancies picking this one apart.

Comment: See my edit (I am writing just now)

Comment: My edit is ready with the SQL fiddle

Comment: You are aware that the SQL in the `SQLFiddle` does not fail? It doesn't return any rows either? Are you missing some test data from the tables. I would not expect any table to be empty? What rows are you expecting to be returned? Please add expected results to your question.

Comment: As I said in my previous edit I expect to obtain ALL the clients with the number of invited and done actions. It always must return rows. What is wrong is that I can't reference the main table id in the subquery. I will post an alternative way I have found just now.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to move the check for table_cl.id from the lowest level of the sub query out to a higher level where (hopefully) MySQL would recognise it. But I am a little concerned about how the sub queries work with how you group by id_accion without bringnig it back. Makes it difficult to trace.

However, a best guess where the check for table_cl.id is in the highest level of the sub query. Can't really do any testing without the table declares though.

```
SELECT table_cl.id, table_cl.nombre, table_cl.apellidos, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
            SELECT iauno.id_accion, iauno.id_cliente, iauno.asistencia
            FROM inter_clientes_acciones iauno
            INNER JOIN clientes clientesuno ON clientesuno.id = iauno.id_cliente
            WHERE iauno.id_cliente IN(
                SELECT iasubuno.id_cliente
                FROM inter_clientes_acciones iasubuno
                INNER JOIN acciones acsubuno ON iasubuno.id_accion = acsubuno.id
                WHERE acsubuno.id_proyecto = 3
                GROUP BY iasubuno.id_accion 
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
            ) 
        )caa
    ) as convocado,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)  
        FROM inter_clientes_acciones iados
        INNER JOIN clientes cldos ON cldos.id = iados.id_cliente
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT iasubdos.id_cliente, 
                    id_accion
            FROM inter_clientes_acciones iasubdos
            INNER JOIN acciones acsubdos ON iasubdos.id_accion = acsubdos.id
            WHERE acsubdos.id_proyecto = 3 
            GROUP BY iasubdos.id_cliente, id_accion 
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        ) sub0 ON iados.id_cliente = sub0.id_cliente
        WHERE iados.id_cliente = table_cl.id
    ) as realizado 
FROM clientes table_cl
WHERE table_cl.id_proyecto = 3 AND table_cl.id IN (
    SELECT iatres.id_cliente
    FROM inter_clientes_acciones iatres
    INNER JOIN clientes cltres ON cltres.id = iatres.id_cliente
    WHERE iatres.id_cliente IN(
        SELECT iasubtres.id_cliente
        FROM inter_clientes_acciones iasubtres
        INNER JOIN acciones acsubtres ON iasubtres.id_accion = acsubtres.id
        WHERE acsubtres.id_proyecto = 3
        GROUP BY iasubtres.id_accion 
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        ) 
)
```

EDIT

I have cleaned it up to work, but can't test it with your test data. I have also changed the table names to English just so I can understand them!

But it does execute, and I think it does what you intended the original to do. I think it might be possible to clean it up further, but I am tired, have a cold coming on and it is late!

```
SELECT table_cl.id, 
        table_cl.nombre, 
        table_cl.apellidos, 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM client_actions 
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT client_actions.id_cliente
                FROM client_actions 
                INNER JOIN actions ON client_actions.id_accion = actions.id
                WHERE actions.id_proyecto = 3
                GROUP BY client_actions.id_accion 
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
            ) sub1
            ON client_actions.id_cliente = sub1.id_cliente
        ) as convocado,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM client_actions 
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT client_actions.id_cliente
                FROM client_actions 
                INNER JOIN actions  ON client_actions.id_accion = actions.id
                WHERE actions.id_proyecto = 3 
                GROUP BY id_accion 
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
            ) sub2
            ON client_actions.id_cliente = sub2.id_cliente
            WHERE client_actions.id_cliente = table_cl.id
        ) as realizado 
FROM clients table_cl
INNER JOIN
(
    /* Get all the clients who have been the sole client for an action */
    SELECT DISTINCT client_actions.id_cliente
    FROM client_actions 
    INNER JOIN actions ON client_actions.id_accion = actions.id
    WHERE actions.id_proyecto = 3
    GROUP BY client_actions.id_accion 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) sub0
ON table_cl.id = sub0.id_cliente
WHERE table_cl.id_proyecto = 3
```

Comment: Maybe an explain is required: I have 3 tables, clients, actions and clients_actions (said in english). An action can be created for one client or for multiple client. The purpose of this query is to get this fields: name and surname of the client, number of actions asigned to the client, and number of this actions which the client had assisted, but only the actions (individual actions) assigned to him. I will edit my question to show the schema,